# how to put personal info (address, phone) in header (2)

Tags: moderncv

Similar to the question here:
[how to put personal info (address, phone) in header](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175820/how-to-put-personal-info-address-phone-in-header)
I am using modern cv casual style and want personal info (address, street, phone, email) in the header but below the horizontal line below my name. And this just in the first page.
Could anybody help me with that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Your question is not very clear, please explain better where you want the personal informations.

Comment: I really like the solution given in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176391/merging-banking-and-classic-style-in-moderncv?rq=1 but What to do if I want to keep the footer information of the classic style from page 2 on?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I meant casual.